GeoServer ImageMosaic for scanned maps with input and output color configuration
I would like to publish scanned maps using GeoServer. Creating of data layer as well as publishing is working like a charm but when it comes to preview of published maps, I am getting result below.  In order to solve this problem I have used inputTransparetColor property set to FFFFFF and the result become more meaningfull but a little bit corrupted as second image. The scanned map's boundries are just overlapping and the information in the map is just staying on the result.
Is there a way to get rid of those boundries but keep the map. I have tried editing the shape file from the file explorer when I get from the publising of the layers but I didn't achieve anything by editing the shapefile. Other than that I have set outputTransparentColor to black but it just deleted all information since my map contains both black and white. How do I show them in a correct format ? Is it possible to solve via transparent colors or there isn't any solution except from cutting them with a script based on their boundries.
Map without inputTransparent color

Map inputTransparent color (FFFFFF) added


The 2nd image looks correct to me - the problem is that your maps have a black border and in some (all) cases a title etc. You need to clean up the scans some more before you will get a great result.

And do what Ian says, without ruining each raster's georeference!
